# how to get the bookmarks from fastpdfkit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I'm using FastPdfKit as shown in the link of youtube

[FastPdfKit](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8F63ovh4Rdw&feature=player_embedded#!)

I want to get the bookmarks from this kit.. anyone tried this before ??
thanks in advance

Comment: Which bookmarks do you need? The ones that the user can create for each document inside the `ReaderViewController`? Or the TOC embedded in each pdf document?

Comment: I need the bookmarks that the user created for each document, mean when I added a bookmarks for pdf that I opened, I want to retrieve all of them and out them in NSLog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FastPdfKit bookmarks are managed by the [`BookmarksViewController`](https://github.com/mobfarm/FastPdfKit/blob/master/Classes/Reader/Bookmarks/BookmarkViewController.m), that is instantiated by the `ReaderViewController`.

The bookmarks are saved in the `NSUserDefaults` under the key *bookmarks_DOCUMENT_ID*. Where DOCUMENT_ID is assigned to the `ReaderViewController` on the `documentId` variable.

Take a look at the `BookmarksViewController` [Class](https://github.com/mobfarm/FastPdfKit/blob/master/Classes/Reader/Bookmarks/BookmarkViewController.m) and in particular the `loadBookmarks` method at line 28.

From your view controller just call something like:

```
NSString * bookmarksKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"bookmarks_%@",(documentViewController.documentId)];
NSArray * storedBookmarks = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:bookmarksKey];
```

to get an `NSArray` filled with `NSNumber`s of pages with bookmarks.

Comment: thanks for your answer. to be understood me properly I'll tell you that I use FastPdfKit as a framework like what the video of youTube shows, I create a project and when I press button it opens the pdf using this FastPdfKit, I add some bookmarks then I want when I close the pdf and back again to the viewController (that shows the (open pdf) button) it retrieves all the bookmarks that I created.. any code suggestion?? (keep in mind that I'm new in iphone developing)

Comment: meaning I want to retrieve them in other class when I close the FastPdfKit

Comment: As you use FastPdfKit as framework you are probably using all the classes I mentioned. I'm updating my answer with code.

Comment: I want to ask another question, is this FastPdfKit allows for adding comments and highlight for my document ??

Comment: No, FastPdfKit aim to beautifully read and show pdf documents, not edit them.

Comment: no I don't mean to edit pdf document, I mean to add a comment to a specific page in this document (somehow like search for a specific word in it)

Comment: Yes you can, but there isn't any built in feature. Does the code worked?

Comment: yes the code worked and thanks for your help :) About the comments in my pdf document could you suggest me a code to do this, or could you develop the code to do this comments for me?? because I need this feature seriously

Comment: You can use the support.fastpdfkit.com pages to suggest this feature or send an email to support@fastpdfkit.com.

Comment: is there are any idea to stop the icon that appears when I open the pdf document ??

Comment: I registered with the site of FastPdfKit and I selected free license then downloaded the zip and it seems that it contains the key, is this mean that I have to add this key to Xcode App-Info.plist and this will hide the icon, or you mean that I have to select (basic, plus or extra) license ??

Comment: Yes, the free version includes the opening logo.

Comment: Ok .. thanks, anyway I sent email to support about adding notes and highlights to pdf document, when I expect the respond ??